# Find $n\in N$ for which $2*[\frac{1^2}{2}]+2^2*[\frac{2^2}{3}]+...+2^n*[\frac{n^2}{ n+1}]$

Tags: square-numbers

**Question**

Find $n\in N$ for which

$$2 \times \left[\frac{1^2}{2}\right] + 2^2 \times \left[\frac{2^2}{3}\right] + ... + 2^n \times \left[\frac{n^2}{n+1}\right] = 2^{2025} \times 2022 + 4$$

where $[a]$ is integer part function applied on $a$ (the whole part of $a$)

**Idea**

I tried getting  $2^n \times \left[\frac{n^2}{n+1}\right]$ to a more friendly form, but honestly got to nothing useful.

By brute force, I got to the conclusion that $\left[\frac{n^2}{n+1}\right]$ is always increasing by one... again, I tried demonstrating it but I don't know how.

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Division of polynomials gives you $\frac{n^2}{n+1} = n-1 + \frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: @jjagmath Oooo....and because when $n\geq 1$ $\frac{1}{n+1}<1$ it means that $[\frac{n^2}{n+1}]=n-1$...Am i right?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Does $[a]$ imply integer function applied on $a$ or are they just square brackets? If it the integer function then you must specify it in your question

Comment: @GameTimeWithAryan Yes, this is what it means. I'm gonna edit the post.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU Yes, you're right.

Comment: @jjagmath I tried replacing it and calculating the number, but unfortunately I got stuck...we have to show that $2^2*1+2^3*2+...2^n(n-1)=2^{2025}+4$. Can you help me?

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry...the sum should equal $2^{2025}*2022+4$ and we must find n

Comment: @Aig Of course, sorry.

Comment: Hint: replace $2$ by $x$ and write $S/4$ you'll see $(n-1)x^{n-2}$ appear. Does it ring a bell ? Think of $S/4$ as a big derived expression...

Comment: @zwim The only thing that came into my mind is $ x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to solve $$2^2\cdot 1+2^3\cdot 2+ 2^4\cdot 3+…+2^{n}(n-1)=2^{2025}\cdot 2022+4.$$

Let us calculate the left hand side. We must add a lot of powers of $2$. Arrange them in a triangle:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 & … & 2^n \\
& 2^3 & 2^4 & … & 2^n \\
& & 2^4 & … & 2^n \\
& & & … & \\
& & & & 2^n
\end{array}$$

It is easy to calculate the sum in each row (using $2^k=(2^{k-1}+…+2^3+2^2+2^1)+2$):

$$\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 & … & 2^n & 2^{n+1}-2^2\\
& 2^3 & 2^4 & … & 2^n & 2^{n+1}-2^3\\
& & 2^4 & … & 2^n & 2^{n+1}-2^4\\
& & & … & &\\
& & & & 2^n & 2^{n+1}-2^n
\end{array}$$

Now we summarize the last column: $$2^{n+1}\cdot(n-1)-(2^{n+1}-2^2)= 2^{n+1}\cdot(n-2)+4.$$

It is clear now that $$n=2024.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\lfloor{n^2\over n+1}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor n-1 +{1\over n+1}\right\rfloor=n-1$$

So we get
$$S=2^2\cdot1 +2^3\cdot2+\cdots+2^n(n-1)$$

Now from the GP formula we know
$$
2+2^2+\cdots2^n=2^{n+1}-2
$$

Adding this to S get

$$
S+2^{n+1}-2=2+2^2\cdot2+2^3\cdot3\cdots2^{n-1}(n-1)+2^n\cdot n\\
2S+2^{n+2}-4=2^2+2^3\cdot2+\cdots2^n(n-1)+2^{n+1}n
$$

You can notice rhs looks a lot like S

$$
2S+2^{n+2}-4=S+2^{n+1}n
$$

Rearranging we get
$$
S=2^{n+1}(n-2)-4=2^{2025}2022-4
$$

So clearly n=2024

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in comments, $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}\right\rfloor$ is just $n-1$ in disguise.

And you are asked to calculate $\displaystyle S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(k-1)2^k$

Notice that if we change $2$ by $x$ we get

$\displaystyle\begin{align} S(x)&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(k-1)x^k=x^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(k-1)x^{k-2}=x^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\Big(x^{k-1}\Big)'=x^2\Bigg(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x^{k-1}\Bigg)'\\\\
&=x^2\Bigg(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k\Bigg)'=x^2\bigg(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\bigg)'=\frac{(nx^2-nx-x^2)\,x^n+x^2}{(x-1)^2}\end{align}$

*Note: sums are finite so exchanging sum and derivation is not an issue, just regular stuff expressed in condensed form.*

Now of course we substitute back $x=2$ to get

> $S(2)=(2n-4)\,2^n+4=(n-2)\,2^{n+1}+4$

And $n=2024$ is clearly solution.

*Note for the future:*

When you will see sums later with terms in $nx^n$ or $n^2x^n$ or $\frac {x^n}n$ and so on, think about derivating once, twice or integrating the geometric $g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

For instance rewrite

- $nx^n=xnx^{n-1}=x(x^{n})'$
- $n^2x^n=x^2n(n-1)x^{n-2}+xnx^{n-1}=x^2(x^{n})''+x(x^n)'$
- $\dfrac{x^n}{n}=\int x^{n-1}$

And so on...

You will need to pay attention to starting indices though, but apart from that this is the general technique for such sums.